# WSO2IS - Authenticating user by Mobile number and SMS OTP only without username and password

Tags: wso2-identity-server

Most of the new mobile Apps use Mobile number with SMS OTP to authenticate the user without username/password how can we do the same to generate Access Token using WSO2 Identity Server, considering the following points:

- User have to enter his/her mobile number in the App
- User have to enter the SMS OTP in the App
- WSO2IS to send the SMS OTP
- In the last step to generate Access Token from WSO2 for the user

Following is the expected flow

[Mobile-SMS Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98c0u.png)

Comment: This thread will be helpful for you https://wso2is.slack.com/archives/CDWPC5MUL/p1607696086212700

Comment: It seems is not supported out of the box, will try the custom authentication approach

Comment: Yes it's not supported out of the box

Comment: @AnuradhaKarunarathna I am not able to access the slack thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom authenticator for this and manage SMS-OTPs from the custom authenticator you can follow this [link](https://maneeshaindrachapa.medium.com/integrate-sms-otps-to-your-applications-with-the-wso2-identity-server-ac34898bcc99) and integrate the below two functionalities for your application.

```
SMSOtpService.generateSMSOTP(userId);
```

This will generate a SMS-OTP for the input of `userID` (`scim-id`) and the output will be a `transactionId` alongside with `smsOtp` and through the WSO2IS SMS event handler, you can send OTP too.

```
SMSOtpService.validateSMSOTP(transactionId, userID, smsOTP);
```

This method will validate the SMS-OTP with the input fields of `transactionID`, `userId`(`scim-id`) and `smsOtp`.

You need to do few customizations but basically, you can use these two functions to `generate` and `validate` SMS-OTP

Comment: The link that you shared is unavailable. Can you please share it again